# Converting an Object into a TypedObject of Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to do a little tool that given the answer of an API call, and a predefined type, I can get the result of the call typed and not as a default javascript object.

```js
class A{

  attributeA: string;
  b: B[];
  methodA():string { return "Method A";}
}

class B{
  attributeB:string;
  methodB():string { return "Method B";}
}
```

When I do the API call, i get as a result (Vue3JS with Axios) a javascript object, lets say for example:

```js
{atributeA: "hello",b: [{attributeB:"helloB1"},{attributeB:"helloB2"}]}
```

Becase I want to work with the types A and B, I do the next:

```js
let data: Object = {atributeA: "hello",[{attributeB:"helloB1"},{attributeB:"helloB2"}]};
let a: A = new A();
a=Object.assign(a,data);
```

As a result I get an Object of type A, but that inside, does not have a collection of objects of type B (B[]), it just has an Object[].
Looks like Object.assign, it just does the first level attributes.

¿Does anyone knows a way of converting that json/object into a collection of typescript objects?
In my real projet, I have a lof of nested complex objects.
Thanks

Full example:

```js
class A{
  attributeA: string;
  b: B[];
  methodA():string { return "Method A";}
}

class B{
  attributeB:string;
  methodB():string { return "Method B";}
}

let data: Object = {atributeA: "hello",b: [{attributeB:"helloB1"},{attributeB:"helloB2"}]};
let a: A = new A();
a=Object.assign(a,data);
console.log(a.methodA());
console.log(a.b[0].methodB());   //Error a.b[0].methodB is not a function -> It has not been converted to type B
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but you definitely should not use `String` and `Object` as a types. Please use `string` instead of `String`, `object` or `Record<string, unknown>` or `{[prop:string]:unknown}` instead of Object

Comment: `Object.assign` happens at runtime, by which time all TS information is lost. I think the easiest way is to refactor your class so you have logic and POC separately.

Comment: @captain-yossarian thx for the advise, corrected the use of String for string, but the problem is not related with that.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova thanks, what you say makes all the sense. My idea was to apply same class architecture like in a c# or java app, where the class container of the data already has validation methods and other business logic methods.
What I finally do is to implement a recursive Object.assign in order to convert the JSON to a collection of complex Typescript objects whith its own validation methods for now.
Thx

Comment: How it can be converted to B if you did not even create an instance of class B?